# How do Madhwists agree or disagree with Srivaishnavites regarding Sharanagati?

Tags: sri-vaishnava, madhwa

AFAIK Srivaishnavites believe Bhakti alone without Sharanagati will not lead to Moksha.

Do Madhwists agree or disagree with this?